# Add text to every other cell in row

Tags: vba

I have a complicated loop that will dump two arrays into a table each iteration. I'm hung up on creating the heading labels of all things. I can't think of a way to add the two labels each loop based on scenario name.

Here's what I tried (This is just a reproducible example and not the real code), which overlaps quite obviously.:

```
For Scenario = 1 To 5

    Worksheets("NewBenefitOutput").Range("E1:CZ1").ClearContents
    Worksheets("NewBenefitOutput").Range("D1").Offset(0, Scenario + 1) = "Acc Beneft - " & Scenario
    Worksheets("NewBenefitOutput").Range("D1").Offset(0, Scenario + 2) = "First Year Cost - " & Scenario

Next Scenario
```

The result is supposed to be a table of four prefilled headings and then the 10 empty headings that go: 11,22,33,44,55 starting in E1.

That is, E1 = Acc Beneft - 1 and G1 = Acc Beneft - 2, etc.

That is, F1 = First Year Cost - 1, H1 = First Year Cost - 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, off As Long, Scenario As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("NewBenefitOutput")
ws.Range("E1:CZ1").ClearContents

For Scenario = 1 To 5
    off = (Scenario - 1) * 2 'next offset
    With ws.Range("E1")
        .Offset(0, off) = "Acc Beneft - " & Scenario
        .Offset(0, off + 1) = "First Year Cost - " & Scenario
    End With
Next Scenario
```